# modify the entity object wrapped by a Symfony 2.0 FormBuilder

Tags: symfony

Here's my code:

```
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($signupAttempt)
     ->add('email', 'text', array("label" => "your email:"))
     ->add('password', 'password', array("label" => "your password:"))
     ->add('passwordRepeat', 'password', array("label" => "repeat password:"))
     ->getForm();


  if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
     $form->bindRequest($request);
     $attempt = $form->getData();
     $this->changeSomeAttributesOfSignupAttempt($attempt); // this does not work
     if ($form->isValid()) { // this is not taking into account the modification made inside changeSomeAttributesOfSignupAttempt
        return new Response("data provided are valid - u signiged up!");
     }
  }
```

See my problem? I'd like to make some changes to the entity and expect the form to be aware of such changes. Unfortunately it looks like the changes that I make are not perceived and, as a result, the rules defined in validaition.xml for the class SignupAttempt are not fulfilled.

here's my validation.xml for the entity SignupAttempt:

```
  <getter property="emailInUseAlready">
     <constraint name="False">
        <option name="message">signup_attempt.whole.email_in_use</option>
     </constraint>
  </getter>
```

and the entity class itself:

```
class SignupAttempt {

   protected $id = null;
   protected $email = null;
   protected $password = null;
   protected $passwordRepeat = null;
   protected $emailInUseAlredy = true;

   public function __construct($email = null, $password = null, $passwordReapeat = null) {
      $this->email = $email;
      $this->password = $password;
      $this->passwordRepeat = $passwordReapeat;
   }

   public function getId() {
      return $this->id;
   }

   public function setId($id) {
      $this->id = $id;
   }

   public function getEmail() {
      return $this->email;
   }

   public function setEmail($email) {
      $this->email = $email;
   }

   public function getPassword() {
      return $this->password;
   }

   public function setPassword($password) {
      $this->password = $password;
   }

   public function getPasswordRepeat() {
      return $this->passwordRepeat;
   }

   public function setPasswordRepeat($passwordRepeat) {
      $this->passwordRepeat = $passwordRepeat;
   }

   public function setEmailInUseAlready($bool) {
      $this->emailInUseAlredy = $bool;
   }

   public function isEmailInUseAlready() {
      return $this->emailInUseAlredy;
   }

   public function isSecondPasswordMatching() {
      return $this->password === $this->passwordRepeat;
   }

   public function import(array $data) {
      throw new \RuntimeException("implement this");
   }
}
```

any idea?

Comment: What kind of changes do you want to apply to your entity?
Also, it's not replated to your question but you should use [repeated Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/repeated.html) for your password field. Update your question to show us what the changeSomeAttributesOfSignupAttempt() method do?

Comment: I want to change a boolean property assessing if the email of the signing up user has already been used.

Comment: Then your entity is not configured correctly. If you only want one user per e-mail address, that should be unique in your database and fail a `$form->isValid()` check.

Comment: I added some details to my question that should help understanding the problem in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one performs `$form->isValid()`, the returned (boolean) value is in fact pre-evaluated at the time when the request was bound to the form.

As a result, changing values of the entity returned by `$form->getData()` is totally useless as validation happens beforehand and on the initial values held by the entity object when it is originally created.